# Java compatibility of Java library

Tags: java, gradle, libraries

How do I determine which Java version a Java library is compatible with?

For reference, I need to upgrade the following libraries:

```
// build.gradle

dependencies {
  compile('javax.mail:mail:1.4')
  compile group: 'org.apache.velocity', name: 'velocity', version: '1.7'
}
```

And my Spring Boot project uses Java 8.

I would like to know if newer versions of these 2 libraries will still support Java 8.

Right now, I'm looking at the mvnrepository page for JavaMail API [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail/1.4), but I don't see anything being mentioned about which Java version is being supported.

Comment: Which “newer versions” are you talking about? As you can see on the page you linked yourself, there’s no activity since 2006.

Comment: There's no universal way to indicate this compatibility, so your two options are really just a.) read the documentation/release notes of the library or b.) try it and see if it crashes. One general rule of thumb: minor and patch releases (i.e. 1.4->1.5 or 1.4.1 -> 1.4.4) *tend* to not break compatibility with a JRE.

Comment: @Holger: there's 1.4.7 which is "only" 10 years old as opposed to 14 years old ....

Comment: JavaMail is now [JakartaMail](https://jakartaee.github.io/mail-api/) + [Eclipse Angus](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.angus). And even if you insist on using JavaMail, then you should be using the 1.6.x version, not 1.4 (and especially not the initial 1.4).

Comment: @JoachimSauer so the OP should have looked at the page of that version instead. Not that it matters much as it is still older then Java 8…

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I suppose, the OP did not find the 1.6.x version on [that page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail)

Comment: @Holger That is because Oracle in all their wisdom has been changing artifact names without defining relocation artifacts, or that 1.4 was released as `javax.mail:mail` was probably an error, as only the specification should be under `javax.mail`, while the (original) reference implementation is under groupId `com.sun.mail`, e.g. `com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail` or `com.sun.mail:javax.mail`, and now `org.eclipse.angus:angus-mail`. On top of that mvnrepository.com is not an authoritative reference, it is just an aggregator of information from various Maven repositories..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Spring Boot 2.7, then you should replace that `javax.mail:mail:1.4` dependency with:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

or for Gradle:

```
compile('com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail')
```

(no version, Spring Boot manages it for you, which for Spring Boot 2.7.19 will resolve to `com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail:1.6.7`.)

JakartaMail/JavaMail 1.6.x supports Java 7 and higher.

If you upgrade to Spring Boot 3.x (which requires Java 17), you'll need to use

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.angus</groupId>
  <artifactId>angus-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

or for Gradle:

```
compile('org.eclipse.angus:angus-mail')
```

Going to Spring Boot 3.x would also involve changes in the namespace of the API (from `javax.mail` to `jakarta.mail`), so that will require some code changes.

For Velocity, you probably need to upgrade to version 2.3 (which supports Java 8 or higher), see the [Apache Velocity](https://velocity.apache.org/) site, but I'm not sure what is involved in upgrading from version 1.7 to 2.3, so that might be a lot of work (e.g. see the 2.0 documentation [Upgrading from earlier versions](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/upgrading.html); also check the 2.3 documentation for 2.1, 2.2 and 2.3 changes).